# Angular 2 to post data to asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I am trying to post data from angularjs2 to asp.net mvc controller.

The actual issue is that when I am trying with it then

See how am I trying ?

this is the typescript ---

```
 save(company: Company): Observable<boolean> {     
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
         this._http.post(this._postUrl, /*JSON.stringify(*/company/*)*/, { headers: headers }) 
            .subscribe(
             (data) => {                 
                console.log('Response');               
                new Observable<true>()
            },
             (err) => { console.log(err); new Observable<false>(); },
            () => console.log('Complete')
            );         

         return new Observable<false>();

          }

onSignUpClicked(message: string): void {
        this._service.save(this.company).subscribe(
           res => console.log(res),
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
```

this is the typescript class:

```
import { Address } from '../shared/Address';
import { Contact } from '../shared/Contact';

export class Entity {
    Id: string;
    InsertionTime: Date;
    InsertUserId: number;
    IsDeleted: boolean;
    IsLocked: boolean;
    UpdateTime: Date;
    UpdateUserId: number;
}

export class Company extends Entity {  
    Name: string;
    Address: Address;
    Contact: Contact;
    Password: string;
    ConfirmPassword: string;
    UserName: string;
    RegistrationDate: Date;
    IsActive: boolean;
    NextBillingDate: string;
    TransactionLimit: number
}
```

and C# class

```
public class Company : Entity
    {       
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public Image LogoImage { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime NextBillingDate { get; set; }
        public Int64 TransactionLimit { get; set; }
    }

 public class Entity : IEntity
    {
        public Entity()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            InsertionTime = DateTime.Now;
            IsDeleted = false;
            IsLocked = false;
        }

        public Guid Id
        {
            get;set;
        }

        public DateTime InsertionTime
        {
            get;set;
        }

        public int InsertUserId
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public bool IsDeleted
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public bool IsLocked
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public DateTime? UpdateTime
        {
            get;set;
        }

        public int? UpdateUserId
        {
            get; set;
        }

    }
```

any help appreciated

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic call to the server from an ng2 app:

```html
getMeSomeServerData(someVar: string): Promise < IGenericRestResponse > {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
      let url = "/getMeSomeServerData";
      let post = this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(someVar), {
        headers: headers
      }).map(response => response.json());
      return post.toPromise();
    }
```

And on the asp.net mvc backend:

```js
// this of course goes within a controller
 [HttpPost()]
 [Route("getMeSomeServerData")]
 public JsonNetResult GetMeSomeServerData(string someVar) {
   GenericRestResponse response = new GenericRestResponse();
   response.Error = false;
   // do somthing 
   return new JsonNetResult(response);
 }
```

JsonNetResult is simply a custom method for serializing an object into json.  Obviously, you can  modify someVar and IGenericRestResponse to your own needs.

On the client side, you also can return an Observable instead of a promise; the promise method is more familiar to me, so I use it unless I need some of the special functionality of an Observable.

Comment: does this also support a generic typed endpoint?  Like
public JsonNetResult GetMeSomeServerData<T>(string someVar) {...

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure.  I have ported all my endpoints to Asp.net Core and so my answer, if I put it up today, would look a little different.  But my feeling is....no.